# Unable to create Always On Basic Availability Group on SQL 2019 Standard, cannot enable Always On feature

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, basic-availability-groups

I want to create a SQL 2019 Standard **BASIC** Always On Availability Group for a database in a 2-node cluster.

By following this guide that should be possible although there are limitations compared to Enterprise edition.

http://woshub.com/configure-always-high-availability-groups-sql-server/

> Always On is available in the Standard edition, but it has some
> restrictions:
>
> - It is limited to 2 replicas (primary and secondary)
> - The secondary    replica cannot be used to read data
> - The secondary replica cannot be    used to backup MS SQL
> - Only 1 database per availability group is    supported.

One of the first steps to enable Always On is to set this feature to enabled in the "SQL server configuration manager". But it shows me that my edition does not support Always On.

What am i doing wrong? I already updated to SQL 2019 CU15 hoping the update would fix this, but no.

Please help out.

I am running standard edition:
*Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)   Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )*

[image]

Comment: Are you positive you're running Standard edition and not Express? What is returned by SELECT @@VERSION?

Comment: Yes I am sure :)
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)   Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: Have you already installed and configured failover cluster services?

Comment: This can happen if the WMI queries are failing. You'll want to collect a trace of WMI to make sure the queries are returning properly (and that the repository isn't broken).

Comment: Yes, Failover Cluster Services is configured. @Sean, any more info about WMI? I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Or better said, how to repair. Maybe good to note, these servers are also domain controllers. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that my servers were also domain controllers.
Always-on is not supported on domain controllers, so it seems.

I tried the same setup on different servers which are not domain controllers, and I can enable Always On in SQL 2019 standard just fine.